# Hyperlinking text to a function perl CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

I have an option on my social media website to search for users.

After searching for users I display the searched users name and username in plain text. **I want to make it so the user can click on the plain text and be redirected to the user's profile they searched for**.

So far I searched for CSS which would help me achieve this but **all of them link to a url but I want to call a function instead. Is this possible?**

Comment: What function do you mean? A Javascript one?

Comment: @choroba A function within my Perl script

Comment: How have you implemented the search?

Answer (score 1):

No. The functions don't exist outside of the Perl, which runs on the server.

The browser can only interact with the Perl by requesting URLs from the server.

You need to map the URLs on to the functions you want to run.

If you're doing this by hand, you would typically do something like:

```
my $action = $q->param('action');
if ($action eq "show_user") {
    show_user();
}
```

Frameworks such as [Catalyst](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst), [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer), and [Web::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Simple) provide routing systems to make this easier.

For example, in Catalyst (probably the most complex of the options I suggested above, but the one I'm most familiar with) you might do something like:

```
sub show_user : Local : Args(1) {
    # code to run in http://example.com/show_user/gettingthere is requested
    my ($self, $c, $username) = @_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't put links in plain text. So I suspect that you're actually returning HTML.

Secondly, I'm not sure why you think that CSS would be the right too for changing how your links work. CSS is for changing appearance, not behaviour.

On most social media web sites, each user has a profile page and that page has a URL. So shouldn't your search results just include those profile page links rather than a call to some Perl function?

All in all, you seem rather confused. I think you should probably have another go at explaining what you're doing - as currently it's really not very clear. Perhaps include some code - that usually clarifies things.